# How to know if a project implemented mutation testing in SonarQube, programatically?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube-web, mutation-testing

I am working on adding plug-ins to my company's SonarQube dashboard. They wanted me to put 2 labels on the dash board, **The Total number of projects that have mutation testing** and **The projects that need Mutation testing**.

I am using *SonarQube Java API* along which AngularJS for UI.I am looking for help on how to do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a plugin to do this?

Comment: No, I just need count of projects having mutation tests So that I can display it on my dashboard as a label.

Answer (score 3):

The closest you can come with out-of-the-box features is setting a custom Metric to indicate whether mutation testing is needed, implemented, or not-needed.

Then you can do a Measures search to find the relevant projects, and use a Measure Filter Widget to display the search results on your dashboard.